# Download a string as a file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file, download, stream, response

The following method, based on code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094398/download-a-string-as-a-file), shows a file download dialog box in the browser, but then the download never starts (it stays at 0%):

```
protected void lnkExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SelectRecords()); //Data to be downloaded
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.xls\"");
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
    stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
  }
}
```

Any idea what's up?

Comment: That's not an Excel file, and you shouldn't lie and say that it is.

Comment: True, SelectRecords() actually returns an HTML table. However, the intention is that Excel should open it (which it can) and the easiest way is to give it an .xls extension. :)

Comment: I believe that that will result in an Excel security warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me but you may want to try adding this as the last line of your click handler:

```
Response.End();
```

Comment: Actually it was an HttpModule trying to GZip the Response stream, so I had to set Response.Filter = null; and Response.ClearHeaders(); However your answer led me to this since you said the code worked for you!